# Mocking Rspec any_instance_of method return value relative to instance's actual args

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I'm running into an issue where I'm trying to mock out an async method in a service class, but I want the result set to be based on the inputs to the call.

eg:

```ruby
allow_any_instance_of(Emails::EmailService)
  .to receive(:send_many_async)
  .and_wrap_original { |m, *args| args[1].map { |recipient| Emails::EmailResult.new(recipient.email) } }
```

The signature for this method is `send_many_async(email, users)`

I don't think that `and_wrap_original` is behaving as I expect though, as when I print out the values for `m` and `args` I see:

```ruby
#<Method: Emails::EmailService#__send_many_async_without_any_instance__(send_many_async)>
#<Emails::EmailService:0x007fa5c4e1b448>
#<Emails::MyEmail:0x007fa5c4e1b4e8>
```

As in, where I would expect `arg[0]` to be the `email` object, and `arg[1]` to be the list of users -- instead `arg[0]` is the service I'm mocking and there is no users list at all (eg: an `arg[2]`)

I effectively just want to confirm the method is called, and that the users are the count I expect them to be.

Alternatively, if I could substitute the method for another on the same class that would work too (the non-async call) but I haven't been able to find a way to replace `:send_many_async` with the regular `:send_many` which is successfully mocked in another way (that I cannot apply here)

Anyone succeed doing something like this? I was expecting `and_wrap_original` to provide what was passed into the instance's method, but clearly I am confused in this regard.

*Edit*

If anyone is wondering, here's a working test sample. It's unfortunately not working for me quite yet in my application but others may find it helpful.

```ruby
class TestEmailSvc
  def send_many_async(email, to_email_users, from_email_user: nil, send_at: nil)
    puts 'Real one called!'
  end
end

class TestEmail
end

class TestEmailUser
  attr_reader :email
  def initialize(email)
    @email = email
  end
end

class TestEmailResult
  attr_reader :user
  def initialize(user)
    @user = user
  end

  def status
    :pending
  end
end

describe 'Test Spec' do

  it 'tests my mock' do
    allow_any_instance_of(TestEmailSvc)
      .to receive(:send_many_async)
        .and_wrap_original { |m, _, args| args.map { |recipient| TestEmailResult.new(recipient) } }

    svc = TestEmailSvc.new

    users = [
      TestEmailUser.new('email 1'),
      TestEmailUser.new('email 2')
    ]

    results = svc.send_many_async(TestEmail.new, users)

    expect(results.count).to eql 2
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `allow_any_instance_of(...).to receive(...).and_wrap_original`, the block receives the following:

- The original method
- The instance that received the message (in case you want to use any of the state of the instance in your block)
- The arguments passed by the caller, in order

In your case, it sounds like you don't need to use the `EmailService` instance in your block, so you can just ignore that argument:

```
allow_any_instance_of(Emails::EmailService)
  .to receive(:send_many_async)
  .and_wrap_original { |m, _, *args| args[1].map { |recipient| Emails::EmailResult.new(recipient.email) } }
```

Alternately, I'd encourage you to consider if there's a way to improve the interface of `Emails::EmailService` so that you don't need to use `any_instance` (which suffers from these sorts of confusing usability problems and also tends to calcify existing designs instead of putting pressure on your design).  We talk about this in my book [Effective Testing with RSpec 3: Build Ruby Apps with Confidence](https://pragprog.com/book/rspec3/effective-testing-with-rspec-3).

Comment: Unfortunately when I do that `args` is received as `nil`... it seems like I have some digging to do, but the call made is simply `email_service.send_many_async(email, recipients)` -- the strange thing is that I'm able to create a demo test that works the way you describe (the only change I had to make, was to use `args` not `*args`) so really confused why it doesn't work with my actual case.

Comment: The block does not receive the instance directly. It has to call `m.receiver` to get it.